# redefinition of struct in linux GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am a beginner in programming.I try to compile a c program in linux, gcc written by the others and got the following error .

cmd.h:145: error: redefinition of ‘struct stat’.

It seems somebody has defined the struct 'stat' more than once. But since there are lots of code files, i dont know how to solve it.Can anyone advise me on that. Thanks

Comment: How do you include files, where struct is defined?

Comment: @user647868 If you're going to completely change your question, please ask a separate question, perhaps deleting the old one, rather than editing the old one -- that completely confuses the heck out of people and results in what look like erroneous answers. We like to be helpful, but you need to be as well.

Comment: Also, you accepted an answer mighty quickly. You might want to wait a bit and see what other suggestions come in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `grep -r "struct stat" *` to find the definition?  Try your own code first then check for definitions in `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include`.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you try to define own structure type, which is already defined in standard headers. 
**struct stat** is defined in **sys/stat.h** [see here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html) (containing file stat info) and it's included directly or through other headers.

A better approach is to use prefix for your type definition, for example, **typedef struct myprog_cmd_stat { ... };** . The latter will also allow to quickly understand where it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I would suggest to create a **makefile** and use [`make`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) to compile your code. [Example](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/).</strike>

Comment: @steve-o, nah, OP changed his question.

Comment: +1 Because you don't deserve a -1 because the OP changed his question... maybe just delete your answer?

Comment: @Steve-o Please remove your downvote -- better for both you and The Elite Gentleman, and it was inappropriate (not that you knew that).

Comment: Sorry guys, I just saw that the question is totally rephrased. Is it still worth it for me to delete this?

Answer (score 0):

Compile with cc -E, which will produce the preprocessor output. Scan that for occurrences of struct stat; the `# filename lineno` lines emitted by the preprocessor will tell you where the definition occurs.

=== edit ===

Even better:
Compiling

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat {};
```

produces the messages

```
foo.c:3:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct stat’
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:43:8: note: originally defined here
```

Which says exactly where the clash occurs. I'll bet that you get similar messages and have simply overlooked it.